# Not able to mock correctly

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

In a spring-boot application, I do some call to moneris. I would like to mock this part.

In a service class:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void saveCreditCard(CreditCardInfoDto creditCardInfo) throws CreditCardException, ResourceNotFoundException {
     ...
     ResolveData resdata = null;
     ResolverReceipt resreceipt = null;
     ...
     ResAddCC resAddCC = new ResAddCC(creditCardInfo.getCreditCard(), expirationDate, String.valueOf(paymentGateway.getCryptType()));
     resAddCC.setCustId(member.getMemberId().toString());


     ResolverHttpsPostRequest mpgReq = new ResolverHttpsPostRequest(paymentGateway.getHost(), paymentGateway.getStoreId(), paymentGateway.getApiToken(), resAddCC);
     resreceipt = mpgReq.getResolverReceipt();
     resdata = resreceipt.getResolveData();

                ...
     if (resreceipt != null && resreceipt.getResponseCode() != null && Integer.getInteger(resreceipt.getResponseCode()) < 50) {
                   ...

     }
```

When I debug, i see then resreceipt is not null, same thing with resreceipt.getResponseCode() but that do un Null Pointer Exception on this line.

Real value vs Mock?

It seem that unreal call is done to moneris... I would like to avoid that.

In my class test I have:

```
@InjectMocks
PaymentServiceImpl paymentService;

@Mock
MemberRepository memberRepository;

@Mock
PaymentGatewayConfigRepository paymentGatewayConfigRepository;

@Mock
OperationRepository operationRepository;

@Mock
ResolverReceipt resreceipt;

@Mock
ResolverHttpsPostRequest mpgReq;

@Before
public void initMocks() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

 Mockito.when(memberRepository.findOne(memberId)).thenReturn(member);

    Mockito.when(paymentGatewayConfigRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(paymentsGateway);

    ResolverReceipt resreceipt = new ResolverReceipt("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <receipt>   <DataKey>iZxTfRWZaRd3S2lajvoZaPA22</DataKey>   <ReceiptId>null</ReceiptId>   <ReferenceNum>null</ReferenceNum>   <ResponseCode>001</ResponseCode>   <ISO>null</ISO>   <AuthCode>null</AuthCode>   <Message>Successfully registered CC details.</Message>   <TransTime>19:13:52</TransTime>   <TransDate>2016-12-09</TransDate>   <TransType>null</TransType>   <Complete>true</Complete>   <TransAmount>null</TransAmount>   <CardType>null</CardType>   <TransID>null</TransID>   <TimedOut>false</TimedOut>   <CorporateCard>null</CorporateCard>   <RecurSuccess>null</RecurSuccess>   <AvsResultCode>null</AvsResultCode>   <CvdResultCode>null</CvdResultCode>   <ResSuccess>true</ResSuccess>   <PaymentType>cc</PaymentType>   <IsVisaDebit>null</IsVisaDebit>   <ResolveData>     <cust_id>1</cust_id>     <phone>4506777244</phone>     <email>paul.smith@gmail.com</email>     <note></note>     <crypt_type>0</crypt_type>     <masked_pan>4242***4242</masked_pan>     <expdate>1601</expdate>   </ResolveData> </receipt> ");


    Mockito.when(mpgReq.getResolverReceipt()).thenReturn(resreceipt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to create a [seam](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/311122/210373) in your code where you can alter the code's behavior without changing the code, itself. Essentially, you inject dependencies, rather than having the code instantiate dependencies so that you can mock dependencies when testing. Presently, in your test code, you're forced to use the real value of `resAddCC` and `mpgReq` because the current production code instantiates them via the `new` keyword, rather than using an injected factory and then calling the factory method on the factory object. Using such a factory, you could mock the factory and its call, where it would otherwise call out to Moneris.